# What does wishbone mean in this Robert Frost quote?

Tags: quotations, proverbs

What does the word **wishbone** mean in the following Robert Frost quotation?

Also what is the message conveyed by the quote? Thanks!

> "A person will sometimes devote all his life to the development of one
>   part of his body - the **wishbone**." - Robert Frost

Comment: In Anglo culture, [the wishbone is a bone in a large bird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishbone), like a turkey, that when served whole at a meal (like Thanksgiving in the US), [the bone is used as a 'wishing' competition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furcula#In_folklore), one person takes one side, another the other, and they both pull until it breaks. Whoever gets the top part of the bone with their, gets their unspoken wish fulfilled.

Comment: It means that a person will sometimes spend too much time wishing and not enough time acting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [wishbone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furcula#In_folklore) is a Y-shaped bone in turkeys, geese, etc. A common superstition is that if two people make a wish and pull a wishbone apart with each person holding a branch of the "Y," the person who ends up with the longer portion will have his or her wish come true.

Frost is using this idea as a metaphor for wishing, just like people sometimes use *funnybone* as a metaphor for the sense of humor (e.g., "That joke tickled my funnybone."). So this quote is saying that many people spend their whole lives wishing for things (but perhaps never acting to fulfill their wishes).

Comment: +1 particularly for the highly-relevant reference to (entirely metaphoric) ***funnybone***. There's also the metaphoric usage *"Show some **backbone**!"* (Be brave!).

Comment: Good point. I hadn't thought of that one.

Comment: [The Corporate Bones Check List:](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yo151rfx-xIC&pg=PA69&dq=funnybone+backbone&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_uP5VKrPHM-U7Qb2moG4DQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=funnybone%20backbone&f=false)  **Wishbone** people want things done, but are not willing to try. **Funnybone** people laugh and joke but they pocket their hands and do nothing. **Jawbone** people are long on talk but short on action. **Backbone** people never say die; they are the true Champions in Life! (Plus of course there are people who are just ***bone idle**!* :)

Comment: What about the boneheads? Is there a place for them in this parade of ossified idioms?